# using pandas Series apply using previous data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hope you can help. I am receiving a series of signals with a difference of 30 seconds. My problem is that within each "burst" of signals, the signals have a difference in milliseconds. For example:

```
Burst    Timestamp
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.752
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.818
1    2018-02-14 09:50:47.030
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.990
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.828
1    2018-02-14 09:50:47.989
1    2018-02-14 09:50:47.937
2    2018-02-14 09:51:40.794
2    2018-02-14 09:51:40.985
2    2018-02-14 09:51:41.014
2    2018-02-14 09:51:41.043
2    2018-02-14 09:51:41.928
2    2018-02-14 09:51:42.002
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.788
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.823
3    2018-02-14 09:55:36.092
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.997
3    2018-02-14 09:55:36.018
3    2018-02-14 09:55:36.115
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.918
```

I dont have the "burst" column. What i want to do is asign the same time stamp to all the signals of the same "burst" or a method to obtain de "burst" column, so i can use the .pivot() method. I have more than 10M entries in the data base, right now im doing this with a "For" but it takes more than 10 h to complete the task, I think this can be done with an apply  & a lambda function in a Serie but using 2 elements of the series in the function. The solution that I use right now:

```
def group_by_date(response=pd.DataFrame, secs = int: 2):
    response = response.sort_values(by='timeSource')
    for i in range(1,len(response)):
        if response.timeSource[i] - response.timeSource[i-1]<datetime.timedelta(0,secs):
            response.loc[i,"timeSource"]= response.loc[i-1,"timeSource"]

    return response
```

Note: timeSource is the same column as time stamp
This is driving me crazy, any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to understand you code better:

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
#you do not need default response to class, it is rather meaningless
# you can use type annotations instread in python 3.6+
#def group_by_date(response=pd.DataFrame, secs = 2):    
def group_by_date(response: pd.DataFrame, secs: int = 2):
    # is timeSource the same column as Timestamp? or it is a different one?
    response = response.sort_values(by='timeSource')
    for i in range(1,len(response)):
        # 'de' is 'of'?
        print(str(i) +" de "+str(len(response)))
        # ERROR: now what is *segundos*? you means *secs*?
        if response.timeSource[i] - response.timeSource[i-1]<datetime.timedelta(0,segundos):
            # you are replacing newer value with an older one?
            response.loc[i,"timeSource"] = response.loc[i-1,"timeSource"]
    return response
```

Basically, I think you can create another series with a shift 
and apply a function of the two series to get the burst. This is probably
as much looping but you can hope it is faster inside pandas. Also a print statement consumes some of your CPU time, consider removing it.

I need the clarifications on the exictign code before solution.

UPDATE: code below should work

```
doc ="""1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.752
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.818
1    2018-02-14 09:50:47.030
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.990
1    2018-02-14 09:50:46.828
1    2018-02-14 09:50:47.989
1    2018-02-14 09:50:47.937
2    2018-02-14 09:51:40.794
2    2018-02-14 09:51:40.985
2    2018-02-14 09:51:41.014
2    2018-02-14 09:51:41.043
2    2018-02-14 09:51:41.928
2    2018-02-14 09:51:42.002
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.788
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.823
3    2018-02-14 09:55:36.092
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.997
3    2018-02-14 09:55:36.018
3    2018-02-14 09:55:36.115
3    2018-02-14 09:55:35.918"""

# change this to faster import for real file 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(doc), 
                 header=None, 
                 sep='    ', 
                 engine='python',
                 names=["burst",  "time"], 
                 converters={'burst':int, 'time':pd.Timestamp})
df = df[['time']]
# find bursts
df['lag'] = df['time'].shift(1)
threshold = datetime.timedelta(seconds=2)
df['delta'] = df['time'] - df['lag']
df['is_new_group'] = df['delta'] > threshold
df['burst'] = df['is_new_group'].cumsum()
# oneliner, skipping saving intermediate columns
df['burst2'] = ((df['time']- df['time'].shift(1)) > threshold).cumsum()
assert (df['burst2'] == df['burst']).all()


# maybe the next thing you want is:
group = df.groupby('burst')
# assuming the timestamps are sorted chronoligically
res1 = group.first()['time']
res2 = group.count()['time']
# again a one-liner
res = group['time'].agg(['first','count'])
```

Comment: thanks for answering! 
>yes, timeSource is same column as time stamp
>yes "de" is "of" i reamoved it anyway as you sugested
>yes "seconds" is "secs" i translated some words from spanish but i left some behind :(
>yes, im replacing newer value with older one

im editing the orignal post

Comment: basically, you want the earliest value in 'burst' and burst is any observation is within 2 seconds?

Comment: see an update, but not sure it is dramatically faster on 10M rows, but you can also try processing a csv in chunks

Comment: Glad running time improved!